# Devise Redirect - Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I use Rails 4.2 and gem devise 3.4
I use helper `form_for` with `remote: true` and action `create` 
with `before action :authenticate_user!`

When user is unauthorized, `authenticate_user` must redirect to `new session path`. This does not happen. In browser i have `401 error + 'You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.'`
How do I configure devise gem?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) devise wiki page, you just need to define `redirect_url`, and override the `respond` method which normally would call devise's `recall` method [(see source here)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/baef67cee7101892e2881a4518030ece6827154f/lib/devise/failure_app.rb):

```
def redirect_url
   new_user_session_url
end

def respond
  if http_auth?
    http_auth
  else
    redirect
  end
end
```